# how Java Application without main method (Karel The Robot)

Tags: java

I was wondering in the program like [Karel the Robot](http://web.stanford.edu/class/cs106a/handouts/H02.pdf). It does not use `main()`, but instead instead it used `run()` method.

```
import stanford.karel.Karel;

public class CollectNewspaperKarel extends Karel {
    public void run() {
        move();
    }
}
```

What is going on?